# Associative array in bash to store all lines start with X

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a file with lines which I am taking input by $1:

```
X B C D E
X G H I J
X L M N 
Y G  
Z B
Y L
```

In each line starts with X, the key is the 2nd element and the values are the rest elements.

I am reading the file line by lines creating associate array for each.

```
while read LINE
do
 INPUT=$(echo $LINE |awk '{print $1}')
 if [[ "$INPUT" = X ]]
 then
     key_name=$(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}')
     declare -A dependencies 
     value_names=($(echo $LINE|awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'))
     dependencies[key_name]=value_names
     echo -e "\nvalues of $key_name are ${key_name[*]}\n"
     sleep 1
 fi
done < $1
```

So I am losing the value for each line reading.

But I need to store all the lines with X in the associate arays, 
because I need to search for the key later for the later lines, lets say:  a line start with Y, and it has `G`, so here I need to find the valuess from the associated arrays
with key G.

Can anyone suggest some idea how to store all lines start with X in a single associative array by reading line line the file? Or any better approach?

Here from the sample input given, the output will be in 3 lines:

```
H I J
C D E
M N
```

Here X,Y,X are recognizing the lines, what to do with the next characters. If `X` store the rest in KEY-PAIR or if `Y` or `Z` extract the values from associative arrays.

Comment: Only one line starts with `X` in your example.

Comment: yes @mgamba, only line start with X. I need to read the file line by line, because I have to read rest of the lines also, which start with different chracter.

Comment: What is `pkg_depends`?

Comment: What is `declare -A dependencies` line doing inside loop?

Comment: Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk so just use that. Post the expected output given your sample input so we can help you.

Comment: Can you just store the chars in a plain array and test for inclusion?

Comment: @anubhava, typo corrected.

Comment: Keep `declare -A dependencies` outside loop otherwise you're initializing it every time.

Comment: @EdMorton, the sample output will be 2 lines printing `H I J` in first line and `A B C` in second line.

Comment: @EdMorton, sorry the output will be 2 lines : 1st line `H I J` and 2nd line `C D E` not `A B C`

Comment: @EdMorton, sample input and output updated in question.

Comment: @EdMorton, here when I read a line starts with `Y`, I will pick `G` and I have to retrive the values with key `G`. Here `Y` or `Z` dont matter, as they always will have a single CHAR next to them. And from that single char I have extract the values from the lines start with `X`. So I have to store all the key-pair values from the lines start with `X`.

Comment: @EdMorton, actually `X,Y,Z`, cant be keys or values. As they are the recognizing the lines what to do for next chars ..

Comment: If you want to be able to quote the contents of each array in such a way as to parse them back out again reliably, what you're doing isn't sufficient. For a more robust mechanism, see https://github.com/threatgrid/declarative.bash/blob/master/declarative.bash#L104 (for putting a list as a value in an associative array safely), and https://github.com/threatgrid/declarative.bash/blob/master/declarative.bash#L60 (for retrieving it).

Answer (score 2):

The declaration should go outside the loop. The variable interpolations need a dollar sign in front. The rest is just refactoring.

```
declare -A dependencies
awk '$1=="X"{$1=""; print }' "$1" |
{ while read -r key value; 
  do
    dependencies["$key"]="$value"
    echo -e "\nvalues of $key_name are ${key_name[*]}\n"
    #sleep 1
  done
  :
  # do stuff with "${dependencies[@]}"
}
```

Comment: +1, but that said, `echo -e`? Do we really want escape sequences inside the expanded variables to be processed? `printf` would allow better control.

Comment: @tripleee, I am not able to retrieve the key-values from outside of the while. How can I ?

Comment: Oops, I thought I left a comment when I updated the answer. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: @PDK, the other approach (if your shell is bash) is to replace `awk | while ... done` with `while ... done < <(awk ...)`, which will also cause your variables to be preserved beyond the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ gawk '{ if (/^X/) a[$2] = gensub(/(\S+\s+){2}/,"",""); else print a[$2] }' file
H I J
C D E
M N
```

The above implicitly loops through every line in the input file and when it finds a line that starts with X (`/^X/`) it removes the first 2 non-space-then-space pairs (`gensub(/(\S+\s+){2}/,"","")`) and stores the result in associative array `a` indexed by the original 2nd field (`a[$2] = ...`), so for example for input line `X B C D E` it saves `a["B"] = "C D E"`. If the line did not start with X (`else`) then it prints the array indexed by the 2nd field in the current line, so for input line `Z B` it will execute `print a["B"]` and so output `C D E`.

With an old version of gawk (run `gawk --version` and check for version before 4.0) you might need:

```
$ gawk --re-interval '{ if (/^X/) a[$2] = gensub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"",""); else print a[$2] }' file
```

but if so youre missing a lot of very useful functionality so get a new gawk!

Comment: I was thinking it to be 100+ liner, but let me taste the power of awk. :). Let me try it for my purpose. Actually I am doing some operations on the values after getting them.

Comment: Mortan, I am getting wrong output with you awk oneliner. I am getting output :`X G H I J`
`X B C D E`
`X L M N` 3 lines with `X` and the Keys included.

Comment: Check your input file for trailing control-Ms as added by WIndows on files it creates, remove them using `dos2unix` if present. Otherwise, edit your question to show the actual script you are executing and the actual input you are running it against because the one I posted would not do that given the sample input file you posted. If you post another question with sample input, expected output, and a clear description of those other operations, I expect you'll get a concise, robust, simple awk solution for that too.

Comment: @EdMortan, I am using linux and the there is no control-M in the file. But with my sample input I am getting the wrong output as in my previous comment. I am doing some simple operation like package installation. As of my sample input, lets say : if I want to install package `G`, I have to install `H`, `I` & `J` first. Then to install `G`. These `H, I, J` are collected from the lines start with `X`.

Comment: Oh hang on - if you're using a very old (pre-4.0) version of gawk then RE intervals won't be enabled by default so try adding the `--re-interval` flag up front. Also, if that alone doesn't work try replacing `\S` with `[^[:space:]]` and `\s` with `[[:space:]]` and if either or both of those does it get a newer version of gawk! I just edited my answer to add a version that should work on pre-4.0 gawks too.

Comment: I am using gawk version 3.1.7.

Comment: Yeah, that's very old, you should get a new version. Adding `--re-interval` and MAYBE changing `\s` etc. should do it, per the alternative solution I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61639/discussion-between-pdk-and-ed-morton).